How to clear the geometry data panel inside the data?
I need some help. Is there any way I can check auto smooth in normals, and then the Angle is 30 degrees, add custom split normals data in geometry data, clear edge bevel weight, clear vertex bevel weight, clear edge crease, clear vertex crease is clear, the previous is a ➕ is correct, what script can help me? Because my model has 10,000 to 30,000 objects on it
